# Insert JSON String using JMeter to database

Tags: java, database, json, jmeter

I am working on the project in which I need to make a connection to database and insert lot of rows in that Database. I have two columns currently in that database-

```
ID         String PrimaryKey
ACCOUNT    String
```

So I need to insert lot of rows in these two columns with the help of JMeter. I am able to generate random Unique ID for ID column by using this-

`${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString())}`

I am trying to insert `JSON String` into ACCOUNT columns using `JMeter`. Below is the JSON string that I am trying to insert.

`{"lv":[{"v":{"regId":null,"user":null,"Id":996},"cn":1}],"lmd":1360185}`

In the parameter values section in JMeter, I am passing something like this-

```
${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString())} ,{"lv":[{"v":{"regId":null,"user":null,"Id":996},"cn":1}],"lmd":1360185}
```

This is my SQL-

`INSERT INTO TEST2 (id, account) values (?, ?)`

But after trying to insert, I am getting this exception-

```
Response message: java.io.IOException: Cannot have quote-char in plain field:[{"]
```

How can I fix this thing? I just need to insert JSON string in the `ACCOUNT column`

Any thoughts how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape all double quotes with a backslash. Something like this:

```
{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regId\":null}}]}
```